# Máximo, mínimo, suma y producto de los elementos de un array

Tags: c

Necesito hallar el elemento máximo y mínimo, intercambiar la posición del máximo con el mínimo y calcular la suma y el producto de todos los elementos.

Mi intento corre sin errores, pero la respuestas de la suma, el producto y el cambio no son correctas. Por favor si me podrían ayudar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() 
{
    int m[8];
    printf("\nInput the elements of the array: ");

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &m[i]); }

    int max=m[0], min=m[0];
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if(max < m[i]) {
        max=m[i];  }
        if(min > m[i]) {
        min=m[i];  }  }

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)  {
        if(m[i] == min)  {
            m[i] = max; } }
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if(m[i] == max) {
            m[i] = min;  } }

    int sum=0, x=0;
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        sum += m[i];
        x = m[i]*m[i];  }

    printf("\n Maximum element: %d", max);
    printf("\n Minimum element: %d", min);
    printf("\n Sum of all elements: %d", sum);
    printf("\n Product of all elements: %d", x);

    printf("\n\n Array with the maximum and minimum elements changed:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        printf("%d", m[i]);
        printf(" ");  }

    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en el par de bucles que intercambian los valores mínimo y máximo.

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)  {
    if(m[i] == min)  {
        m[i] = max; } }

for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    if(m[i] == max) {
        m[i] = min;  } }
```

El segundo for de arriba, pisa lo que estableció el primero, pues max esta 2 veces en el arreglo al comenzar el segundo for, por lo que al final el valor max se pierde y el valor min queda 2 veces en el arreglo final.

Sugerencia de solución:

```
/* cuando buscas el minimo y el maximo almacena sus posiciones */
int max=m[0], min=m[0], minIx = 0, maxIx = 0;

for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    if(max < m[i]) {
        max=m[i];
        maxIx = i;  
    }
    if(min > m[i]) {
        min=m[i];  
        minIx = i;
    }  
}
```

Luego solo intercambias los valores con los indices.

```
int temp = m[maxIx];
m[maxIx] = m[minIx];
m[minIx] = temp;
```

Y elimina esos bucles que intercambian los valores mínimo y máximo.

Por ultimo, en el producto veo un error, quizá deberías hacer algo así, pues lo que ahora tienes en tu código es una potencia y solo obtendrás el valor del ultimo elemento del arreglo.

```
int sum=0, x=1; // usa 1, el primer ciclo establece el primer valor
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    sum += m[i];
    x = x * m[i]; // lo anterior era una potencia y siempre pisaba el valor.  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar declarar una variable max y min, y compararlas entre sí con un for, al final el valor que almacenen estas variables será el maximo o el minimo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int promedio;
    int numbers[5];
    int max, min;

    printf("\nIngrese los elementos del array array: ");

    for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[j]); }

    printf("Tengo un array de 5 elementos\n");

    for(int f=0;f<5;f++){
        printf("%d, ",numbers[f]);  
    }

    promedio = (numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2] + numbers[3] + numbers[4])/5;
    max=numbers[0], min=numbers[0];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        if(max < numbers[i]){
            max=numbers[i];
        }
        if(min > numbers[i]){
            min=numbers[i];
        }
    }

    printf("\nEl promedio de 10,20,30,40,60 es: %d", promedio);
    printf("\nEl maximo de 10, 20, 30, 40, 60 es: %d", max);
    printf("\nEl minimo de 10, 20, 30,40, 60 es: %d\n", min);

    return 0;
}
```